# jQuery how to add element to a selection cached in a variable using add()

Tags: jquery

I am storing a collection of elements in a variable.

I would like to add an element to this selection using `myvariable.add('#myselector')`

However, I can't have it working: the length and the content of the collection remains the same and the new element is not added.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7dvcLoL3/)

Is it authorized to use `.add()` on a javascript variable instead of a jQuery collection like `$('......')` ?

Thanks

Comment: try myvariable.append()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The add() method doesn't change the original object, it creates a new object. In this case, you would have to set the value of collection to the new object that is created:

```
$(function(){
    var collection = $('#foo');
    console.log(collection);

    collection = collection.add('#bar');
    console.log(collection);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the jQuery docs ([`.add()` method](https://api.jquery.com/add/)):

> Create a new jQuery object with elements added to the set of matched elements.

Therefore you aren't actually modifying the `collection` variable in your example. You were logging the same, unmodified variable each time. You need to assign the newly created object back to the `collection` variable:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/g52g09va/)

```
$(function () {
    var collection = $('#foo');
    console.log(collection);

    collection = collection.add('#bar');
    console.log(collection);
});
```